# Parse Text File with Variable Fields Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, parsing

A text file that I process has changed in the way data is formatted, so it's time to update the code that parses it.  The old file had a fixed number of lines and fields per record and so parsing it by position was easy, of course now that isn't the case (I added the spaces for readability, the ~ indicates a new line, the * is the field separator):

~ENT*1*2J*34*111223333 
~NM1*IL*1*SMITH*JOHN*A***N*123456789 
~RMR*IK*H62XX/PAY/1234567/20150103**12345.67 
~REF*ZZ*MEDPM/M/12345.67 
~REF*LU*40/CSWI 
~DTM*582****RD8*20150101-20150131

~ENT*2*2J*34*222334444 
~NM1*IL*1*DOE*JANE*S***N*234567891 
 ~RMR*IK*H62XX/PAY/1234567/345678901**23456.78 
~REF*LU*40/CSWI 
~DTM*582****RD8*20141211-20141231

~ENT*3*2J*34*333445555 
~NM1*IL*1*DOE*JOHN****N*3456789012 
 ~RMR*IK*H62XX/PAY/200462975/20150103**45678.90 
~REF*ZZ*MEDPM/M/3456.78 
~REF*LU*40/CSWI 
~DTM*582****RD8*20150101-20150131

~ENT*4*2J*34*444556666 
~NM1*IL*1*SMITH*JANE*D***N*456789012 
 ~RMR*IK*H62XX/PAY/567890123/678901234**6789.01 
~REF*ZZ*MEDPM/M/6789.01 
~REF*LU*40/CSWI 
~DTM*582****RD8*20150101-20150131

~ENT*5*2J*34*666778888 
~NM1*IL*1*SMITH*JON*J***N*8901234 
~RMR*IK*H62XX/PAY/56789012/67890123**5678.90 
~REF*ZZ*MEDPM/M/5678.90 
~REF*LU*40/CSWI 
~DTM*582****RD8*20150101-20150131

~ENT*6*2J*34*777889999 
~NM1*IL*1*DOE*BOB*E***N*567890123 
~RMR*IK*H62XX/PAY/34567890/45678901*5678.90 
 
~REF*LU*40/CSWI 
~DTM*582****RD8*20141210-20141231 
 ~RMR*IK*H62XX/PAY/1234567890/2345678901**6789.01 
~REF*ZZ*MEDPM/M/6789.01 
~REF*LU*40/CSWI 
~DTM*582****RD8*20150101-20150131

What is the best way to parse this data?  Is there a better way than using StreamReader?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Right now I'm thinking of just using StreamReader with System.IO.File but there is the TextFieldParser class...maybe that's a a better way?

Comment: Normally the ~ in an EDI document is at the end of each segment and not the beginning.  But @Heinzi is correct, using `String.Split` works well with EDI segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) is your friend.

If the file is not too large, the simplest approach would be to:

- Read the file contents into a string variable (`File.ReadAllText`).
- Split the "lines" (`lines = allText.Split("~"c)`).
- Loop through the lines. For each line:

  - Split the line into fields (`fields = line.Split("*"c)`)
  - Process the field values. You'll probably want to have a big `Select Case` statement on `fields(0)` and then proceed depending on the first field of the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this into an 2-D array fairly easily:

```
' Dynamic structure to hold the data as we go.
Dim data As New List(Of String())

' Break each delimiter into a new line.
Dim lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("data.txt").Split("~")

' Process each line.
For Each line As String In lines
    ' Break down the components of each line.
    data.Add(line.Split("*"))
Next

' Produce 2-D array. Not really needed, as you can just use data if you want.
Dim dataArray = data.ToArray()
```

Now just iterate through the 2-D structure and process the data accordingly.

If you need to ensure your data *always* has a specific number of indexes (for example, some lines have 5 fields supplied, but you expect there to always be 8), you can can adjust the `data.Add` command like so:

```
' Ensure there are always at least 8 indexes for each line.
' This will insert blank (String.Empty) values into the array indexes if a line of data omits certain values.
data.Add((line & Space(8).Replace(" ", "*")).Split("*"))
```